# Angular 7 ngx-translate doesn't remember the language after refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-translate

We have an Angular application which has two languages. The default is German and the other one is English. We are using `ngx-translate` as the `translateService`.

**When you refresh the browser, the application switches back to the default language.**

The `switchLang()` function gets called in our navigation bar:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="switchLang" (click)="switchLang()">
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span>{{'switch-lang' | translate}}</span>
      </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

**the component.ts:**

```
switchLang() {
    this.languageService.switchLanguage();
}
```

And the **language service**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LanguageService {

  private language = 'de';

  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) { }

  getCurrentLanguage() {
    return this.language;
  }

  getLocale() {
    if (this.language === 'en') {
      return 'en_US';
    } else {
      return 'de_DE';
    }
  }

  switchLanguage() {
    if (this.language === 'en') {
      this.language = 'de';
    } else {
      this.language = 'en';
    }
    this.translateService.use(this.language);
  }
}
```

The `translateService` is the **ngx-translate**.

Comment: Well you're saving it nowhere. When you refresh the page the whole application recompiles.

Comment: I thought the ngx-translate has a built-in method for that. I think the localStorage is the direction

Comment: i also recommend you to initialize your default lang by using the browser langage. `const userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the right behavior. You can use localStorage (or other place) to store the selected language.

Comment: I see that translation has its own storage. What if I want at each translate pipe (... | translate) to get the data from local-storage, without changing much the code (a thought that there is a property for that). Also - using translateService.setTranslation(....) will automatically use the 'LocalStorage' db.

Answer (score 2):

You can use localStorage to store the value in device memory, the following is an example

```
 // function select language
  selectLanguage(i: number) {
    this.lag = this.languages[i];
    this.translateService.use(this.languages[i].title.toLowerCase());
    localStorage.setItem("language",this.languages[i].title.toLowerCase());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular service lives entirely in memory. If you want to add a persistence you should save current value to the localStorage on a language change or save this setting to the server